# CoreData relationship returns a _NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm accessing a core data object through a relationship with :

```
pArret.zzone?.libelle
```

The first object has a To-one relationship to the second and `libelle` is a property of the second object.

I'm getting the following error:  `-[_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID libelle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd00000000e30000c`. I don't get what's this private `_NSCoreDataTaggedObjectID` class and why am I not getting my `NSManagedObject` subclass as expected ?!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check your KVO. In my case it was because I was using `addObserver` with `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` and a custom property method that has a `keyPathsForValuesAffecting` method and in its getter I was accessing a relationship property. The KVO mechanics `NSKeyValueWillChangeBySetting` calls the getter as the object is being faulted (all setters are being called causing valuesAffecting calls) and runs so early that the relationship object hasn't been loaded yet. First attempt at a workaround was to observe the keys involved in the `keyPathsForValuesAffecting` directly instead of the custom property key name.